# Convert jobject to Integer in JNI C++ and parse the intValue

Tags: java-native-interface

I have following code which accepts int value at JAVA level

```
dataObj.property(20);
```

This is the definition of property function

```
void property(Object value){
     // JNI called
}
```

JNI function definition

```
Java_com_XXX_XXXX_JNIProperty(JNIEnv *a_pEnv, jclass, **jobject a_oPropertyValue**) {
   // how to convert jobject to Integer object and then get the intValue
   jclass cls = a_pEnv->FindClass("java/lang/Integer"); 
   jmethodID getVal = a_pEnv->GetMethodID(cls, "intValue", "()I");
   int i = a_pEnv->CallIntMethod(value, getVal);
}
```

How to convert jobject which was of type **Object** in Java to Integer object in JNI and parse int value ?

Comment: You are pretty close already, actually. Just pass `a_oPropertyValue` to `CallIntMethod` and you're there.

Answer (score 0):

For a class in Java

```
public class PassObject {

  public static native void displayInt(Object obj);

  public static void property(int value) {
    PassObject.displayInt(value);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PassObject.property(44);

    // make sure to be careful in your case, 
    // as you make assumption that "Object" will be of type "Int"
    // It's really easy to be very nasty.

    PassObject.displayInt("44");
  }
}
```

you can use following `JNI` code

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_recipeNo055_PassObject_displayInt
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jobject objarg) {

  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass (env, objarg);

  jmethodID integerToInt = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "intValue", "()I");

  jint result = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objarg, integerToInt);

  printf("Passed value: %d\n", result);

}
```

if you want to be extra careful, you can always do

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass (env, objarg);

if( (*env)->IsInstanceOf(env, objarg, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer")) ) {
  jmethodID intValue = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "intValue", "()I");
  jint result = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, objarg, intValue);
  printf("%-22s: %d\n", "Passed value (int)", result);
} else {
  // error
}
```